# How to sort array in php? through this key ['address-country']

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**Data show in this array format in to page** -->

```
    Array (
[people] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[administrator] =>
[address-city] => Bucharest
[pid] =>
[site-owner] =>
[twitter] =>
[phone-number-home] =>
[last-name] => Buzoianu
[email-address] => dmeo@gmail.com
[userUUID] =>
[user-name] => AdrianB
[company-name] => Ambassadors
[id] => 60536
[last-changed-on] => 2014-03-14T06:32:02Z
[phone-number-office] =>
[address-state] => Bucharest
[address-country] => RO
[notes] =>
[first-name] => Adrian
[user-type] => account
[permissions] => Array (
[can-manage-people] =>
[can-add-projects] =>
)
[im-service] =>
[im-handle] =>
[address-line-2] =>
[address-line-1] => AL. Rotunda nr.4, BL. H6, Scara E, Ap. 81, Sector 3
[created-at] => 2013-09-27T22:48:41Z
[phone-number-office-ext] =>
[company-id] => 19181
[address-zip] => 032705
[phone-number-fax] =>
[in-owner-company] =>
[last-login] => 2014-03-14T06:30:07Z
[email-alt-1] =>
[email-alt-2] =>
[companyId] => 19181
[email-alt-3] =>
[title] => Ambassador
)
[1] => Array (
[administrator] =>
[address-city] =>
[pid] =>
[site-owner] =>
[twitter] =>
[phone-number-home] =>
[last-name] => Balazsy
[email-address] => dmeo@gmail.com
[userUUID] =>
[user-name] => AnnaB
[company-name] => Ambassadors
[id] => 40047
[last-changed-on] => 2014-03-12T19:48:18Z
[phone-number-office] =>
[address-state] =>
[address-country] => US
[notes] =>
[phone-number-mobile] =>
[first-name] => Anna
[user-type] => account
[permissions] => Array (
[can-manage-people] =>
[can-add-projects] =>
)
[im-service] =>
[im-handle] =>
[address-line-2] =>
[address-line-1] =>
[created-at] => 2013-03-18T18:27:03Z
[phone-number-office-ext] =>
[company-id] => 19181
[address-zip] =>
[phone-number-fax] =>
[in-owner-company] =>
[last-login] => 2013-11-11T15:55:39Z
[email-alt-1] =>
[email-alt-2] =>
[companyId] => 19181
[email-alt-3] =>
[title] =>
)
[2] => Array (
[administrator] =>
[address-city] =>
[pid] =>
[site-owner] =>
[twitter] => billpoli
[phone-number-home] =>
[last-name] => Polizos
[email-address] => demo@gmail.com
[userUUID] =>
[user-name] => billpolizos
[company-name] => Ambassadors
[id] => 38828
[last-changed-on] => 2014-03-13T15:21:07Z
[phone-number-office] =>
[address-state] =>
[address-country] => CND
[notes] =>
[phone-number-mobile] => 7894563210
[first-name] => Bill
[user-type] => account
[permissions] => Array (
[can-manage-people] =>
[can-add-projects] =>
)
[im-service] =>
[im-handle] =>
[address-line-2] =>
[address-line-1] =>
[created-at] => 2013-02-21T17:46:10Z
[phone-number-office-ext] =>
[company-id] => 19181
[address-zip] =>
[phone-number-fax] =>
[in-owner-company] =>
[last-login] => 2014-03-13T14:59:35Z
[email-alt-1] =>
[email-alt-2] =>
[companyId] => 19181
[email-alt-3] =>
[title] =>
)
[3] => Array (
[administrator] =>
[address-city] => Puerto Montt
[pid] =>
[site-owner] =>
[twitter] =>
[phone-number-home] =>
[last-name] => Díaz Pinto
[email-address] => dmeos@gmail.com
[userUUID] =>
[user-name] => DalmaD
[company-name] => Ambassadors
[id] => 88290
[last-changed-on] => 2014-03-12T19:48:37Z
[phone-number-office] =>
[address-state] => Región de Los Lagos
[address-country] => CL
[notes] =>
[first-name] => Dalma
[user-type] => account
[permissions] => Array (
[can-manage-people] =>
[can-add-projects] =>
)
[im-service] =>
[im-handle] =>
[address-line-2] =>
[address-line-1] =>
[created-at] => 2014-03-06T16:48:03Z
[phone-number-office-ext] =>
[company-id] => 19181
[address-zip] => 5505263
[phone-number-fax] =>
[in-owner-company] =>
[last-login] => 2014-03-07T21:16:43Z
[email-alt-1] =>
[email-alt-2] =>
[companyId] => 19181
[email-alt-3] =>
[title] => Directora de Comunicaciones / Director of Communications Gastronomía Patagonia
)
[4] => Array (
[administrator] =>
[address-city] =>
[pid] =>
[site-owner] =>
[twitter] =>
[phone-number-home] =>
[last-name] => Agostini
[email-address] => dmeo67@gmail.com
[userUUID] =>
[user-name] => DanielaA
[company-name] => Ambassadors
[id] => 89822
[last-changed-on] => 2014-03-14T21:10:03Z
[phone-number-office] =>
[address-state] =>
[address-country] => AUS
[notes] =>
[phone-number-mobile] =>
[first-name] => Daniela
[user-type] => account
[permissions] => Array (
[can-manage-people] =>
[can-add-projects] =>
)
[im-service] =>
[im-handle] =>
[address-line-2] =>
[address-line-1] =>
[created-at] => 2014-03-14T21:10:03Z
[phone-number-office-ext] =>
[company-id] => 19181
[address-zip] =>
[phone-number-fax] =>
[in-owner-company] =>
[last-login] =>
[email-alt-1] =>
[email-alt-2] =>
[companyId] => 19181
[email-alt-3] =>
[title] =>
)
)..
```

I need to sort this array data through ['address-country'] key

Comment: format your post please... horrible to read

Comment: http://us.php.net/usort Example #2

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array according to your array structure..
[PHP sorting manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)